# Convert any email format to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, email, outlook, twig

I have a problem with email answers from users.

I use iframe and srcdoc to present email on my site (in srcdoc I put message from user):

`<iframe srcdoc="{{ received.message }}" src="demo_iframe_srcdoc.htm"></iframe>`

and there is a problem when it will be sent in other format then html.
For example I receive something like:

1. Lot of free spaces
2. Formatting like `\n`, `#` or others signes

Is there any chance to convert this message on html in PHP, Twig, JS ?

Comment: Rather than iframe why don't you do read file action and once you have that message text into a PHP variable you can do all kind of cleaning up and formatting and present it nicely in a standard format of your choice. Either plain or HTML whichever you want.

Comment: It sounds ok - could you give me some example?